# python 3 on Debian working in interactive mode but can't run any command

Tags: python-3.x, debian

I successfully installed Python 3.7 on a Debian machine (GCE) and it runs correctly in interactive mode.

```
$python3
Python 3.7.4 (default, May 16 2020, 07:48:36) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

But when I try to perform any command I receive follow:

```
$ python3 ––version
python3: can't open file '––version': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you accidentally used `en dash –` instead of `hyphen -`. Parameters should start with hyphen.

Try:

```
python3 --version
```

Instead of:

```
python3 ––version
```